# Regular expression to replace text

Tags: regex, ultraedit

I am very new to regular expressions. I am using UltraEdit, and would like to use regular expressions to make the changes described below.

I have some text in the following pattern:

```
<Music href="6000111.genre" title="AAA">
    <Music format="ditamap" href="000760.rock" title="222"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="000756.rock" title="333"/>
</Music>
```

I need to add prefix 'Z' in front of `href` with extension `.rock`.

```
href="000760.rock" --> href="Z000760.rock"
```

The output should look like this:

```
<Music href="6000111.genre" title="AAA">
    <Music format="ditamap" href="Z000760.rock" title="222"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="Z000756.rock" title="333"/>
</Music>
```

What would be the regular expression to do this in UltraEdit?

Comment: Is there a way to do the same without Ultra Edit? using a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-wrote my answer to

1. Add new use-case OP added where some values have the X prefix and must not be replaced.
2. I was initially putting the double quote character in brackets when there was no need.

---

The first case I answered is where none of the HREF values already have the X prefix.

Find:

```
href="([^"]*)\.rock"
```

And replace:

```
href="X\1.rock"
```

Start:

```
<Music href="6000111.genre" title="AAA">
    <Music format="ditamap" href="000760.rock" title="222"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="000756.rock" title="333"/>
</Music>
```

Finish:

```
<Music href="6000111.genre" title="AAA">
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000760.rock" title="222"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000756.rock" title="333"/>
</Music>
```

Screen shot showing this first result is below.

[image: Screen shot showing first result.]

Breakdown of the regex:

1. Find: `href="([^"]*)\.rock"`

   1. `href="`  - this finds `href="`
   2. `([^"]*)` - this creates the first backreference - tells the engine to look for and remember everything between the brackets: `[^"]*` so that we can reference it in the replace part.

      1. `[^"]` - this part of the pattern says any character that is not a double quote.
      2. And the asterisk at the end of `[^"]*` is a repetition pattern that says look for zero or more characters that matches the thing just before it (so find zero or more characters that are not a double quote).
   3. `\.rock"` this defines the rest of the pattern which must be `.rock"`
   4. Note that I have escaped the period character: `\.`. That is because period has a special meaning in a regex and we are telling the regex that we mean a literal dot or period.
2. Replace: `href="X\1.rock"`

   1. `href="X` - says to output literally `href="X`..
   2. `\1` - says to replace `\1` with the first backreference we created (zero or more characters that are not a double quote).
   3. `.rock"` - says to output literally `.rock"`.

      1. Note that I didn't need to escape the period here, because it doesn't have the same meaning in replace - it just means the literal dot.

---

The second case is in response to OP's comment that some of the HREF values already have the X prefix. In this case, change the regex as below.

Find:

```
href="([^X][^"]*)\.rock"
```

And replace:

```
href="X\1.rock"
```

Start:

```
<Music href="6000111.genre" title="AAA">
    <Music format="ditamap" href="000760.rock" title="222"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000756.rock" title="333"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="000757.rock" title="444"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000758.rock" title="555"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="000759.rock" title="666"/>
</Music>
```

Finish:

```
<Music href="6000111.genre" title="AAA">
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000760.rock" title="222"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000756.rock" title="333"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000757.rock" title="444"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000758.rock" title="555"/>
    <Music format="ditamap" href="X000759.rock" title="666"/>
</Music>
```

Screen shot showing this second result is below.

[image: Screen shot showing second result.]

Breakdown of the regex:

1. Find: `href="([^X][^"]*)\.rock"`

   1. `href="` - this finds `href="`
   2. `([^X][^"]*)` - this creates the first backreference - tells the engine to look for and remember everything between the brackets: `([^X][^"]*)*` so that we can reference it in the replace part.

      1. `[^X]*` - this part of the pattern says any character that is not an X.
      2. `[^"]` - this part of the pattern says any character that is not a double quote.
      3. And the asterisk at the end of `[^"]*` is a repetition pattern that says look for zero or more characters that matches the thing just before it (so find zero or more characters that are not a double quote).
   3. `\.rock"` this defines the rest of the pattern which must be `.rock"`
   4. Note that I have escaped the period character: `\.`. That is because period has a special meaning in a regex and we are telling the regex that we mean a literal dot or period.
2. Replace: `href="X\1.rock"`

   1. `href="X` - says to output literally `href="X`..
   2. `\1` - says to replace `\1` with the first backreference we created (zero or more characters that are not a double quote).
   3. `.rock"` - says to output literally `.rock"`.

      1. Note that I didn't need to escape the period here, because it doesn't have the same meaning in replace - it just means the literal dot.

Comment: Thanks Robert!works great. one question: How do I modify so that if X is already there then it should not find (or replace). i.e., it only finds '000760.rock' but not 'X000760.rock'. Otherwise, the solution you mentioned adds another X as prefix.

Comment: @user1749707, if the X may (or may not) already be there, use this as your **find**: `href=["]X?([^"]*)\.rock["]` and keep the **replace** the same: `href="X\1.rock"`.

Comment: Hi, I used ["]X?([^"]*)\.rock["] but it finds value with X as well. It shoudl NOT find and replace that already has X prefix. Anything wrong?

Comment: @user1749707, `href=["]X?([^"]*)\.rock["]` would still be ok in most cases because the output would be the same - i.e. you would still end up with all entries having the X before them. Just in case there is some other reason why you would absolutely not want those cases changed, I have added a second solution to my answer for that. I also added explanations of the regular expressions and corrected an error where I was putting double quotes in square brackets when that wasn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for Ultraedit, but I assume it's close to notepad++:

Find what: `(href=")(.+?\.rock")`
Replace with: `$1X$2`

`X` or `Z` as it's not clear in your question.

Comment: Thanks M42 for the help